# concurrent sqlite writes in python

Tags: python, sqlite, gtk

I've got a python application (Gtk) which uses threads to fetch information from certain sites and writes them to the datebase.

I've got a thread that checks for new updates at **site1**, if there are updates I receive a json object (**json1**).
I will then iterate through **json1** and insert the new information to the datebase, within **json1** there is a result I need to use to fetch more information at **site2**. I will recive a json object(**json2**) at **site2** as well.

So the situation is something like this

```
def get_more_info(name):
    json2 = get(www.site2.com?=name....)
    etc

for information in json1:
    db.insert(information)
    get_more_info(information.name)
```

From this situation I see that there are a couple of ways of doing this.

`get_more_info` to return json object so that

```
for information in json1:
    db.insert(information)
    json2 = get_more_info(information.name)
    for info in json2:
        db.insert(info)
db.commit()
```

`get_more_info` to do the inserting

```
for information in json1:
    db.insert(information)
    get_more_info(information.name)
db.commit()
```

Both of these ways seem a bit slow since the main for loop will have to wait for `get_more_info` to complete before carrying on and both **json1** and **json2** could be large, there is also the possiblity that **site2** is unavailiable at that moment, causing the whole transaction to fail. The application can still function without **json2**, that data can be fetched at a later time if needed.

So I was thinking of passing `information.name` to a queue so that the main loop can continue and kick off a thread that will monitor that queue and excute `get_more_info`. Is this the right approach to take?

I know that sqlite does not perform concurrent writes, If I recall correctly if `get_more_info` tries to write while the main for loop is busy, sqlite will output `OperationalError: database is locked`.

Now what happends to `get_more_info` at that point, does it get put into sometype of write queue or does it wait for the main loop to complete and what happens to the main for loop when `get_more_info` is busying writing?

Will there be a need to go to another database engine?

Answer (score 0):

Since you are using threads always, you can use an other thread to write to the database. In order to feed it with the data you should use a globally accessible `Queue.Queue()` (`queue.Queue()` in Python3) instance. Using the instances `get()` method with `block=true` will make the thread wait for data to write.

Comment: I'm not sure if  using a thread that will do the writes will work as for some inserts, notifications will need to be made after the inserts. what I am thinking about is kicking off a new thread and passing `information.name` to a queue then the newly created thread can `q.get`